# Jsreport solution for generating PDF server

Tags: web-services, pdf, jsreport

I would like to ask about naive approach for the following problem regarding using jsreport:

TasK:

```
1. Click a button
2. Send json to server
3. Generate PDF over there
4. Send it back to user.
```

How can I approach this? Do I need to keep jsreport server running on different port and give the json to its API? If then, how can it notify my webserver that the task is done to send the file back?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is common approach to run jsreport as standalone server and send the data required for report generation through API.

The API is by default synchronous, which means you get back the response with the  report stream. In your case you can just pipe the jsreport response to the client.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I want to clarify 1 thing: Jsreport server would send back a stream directly to client who send Post request? or you mean I have to write an, lets say, nodejs webserver between and pipe the stream to client?

Comment: It depends on your use case. You can call report rendering directly from the client, for example using [jsreport browser client](http://jsreport.net/learn/browser-client), but you can also have your server in the middle